# How to customize PullToRefresh to support one action on a small pull and another on a long pull?

Tags: codenameone

For my Codename One app UI I'd like to have two different actions possible when doing a PullToRefresh. One should be done on a small/short pull (e.g. triggered as soon as pull is bigger than zero) and another done on a long pull (e.g. triggered when pulled more than X pixels).

Is there any way to achieve this currently?

Or any hints to how I might add it to CN1 myself for a pull request? Maybe something along the lines of adding a listener which gets called with the length of the pull?

Answer (score 1):

We don't support this sort of behavior in the pull to refresh API. You can avoid our API entirely and just listen to drag events on the form to implement your own pull to refresh functionality. You can render the pull to refresh feature either on the title area or within a glasspane/layered pane.

Comment: What do you think about the idea I mentioned about adding a listener? Would you accept such a pull request?

Comment: From my recollection of the code it really isn't simple. I'm also not sure how such an API would look for someone who isn't interested in that behavior. If you have an outline of the API and an understanding of where it can be file an RFE and we can discuss it there